# Error after adding plone.app.dexterity to Plone 4.3 buildout

Tags: plone, buildout, dexterity

I've used https://github.com/plone/plonedev.vagrant to set up a Plone 4.3 development environment on Windows. I've been trying to add Dexterity support to my installation, but have run into problems.

The steps I have taken are as follows:

1. Added zopeskel.dexterity and plone.app.dexterity [relations, grok] to the [eggs] section of my buildout.cfg
2. Added ZopeSkel <= 2.99 to the [versions] section of buildout.cfg

I re-run buildout and try to start the server in foreground mode, but get this traceback:

```
vagrant@precise32:~$ ./runbin.sh plonectl fg                                                                                                                                                                                       
instance: Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                                                                                                                                       
  File "/home/vagrant/Plone/zinstance/bin/instance", line 290, in <module>                                                                                                                                                         
    import plone.recipe.zope2instance.ctl                                                                                                                                                                                          
  File "/home/vagrant/Plone/buildout-cache/eggs/plone.recipe.zope2instance-4.2.9-py2.7.egg/plone/recipe/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>                                                                                          
    __import__('pkg_resources').declare_namespace(__name__)                                                                                                                                                                        
  File "/home/vagrant/Plone/buildout-cache/eggs/distribute-0.6.28-py2.7.egg/pkg_resources.py", line 2835, in <module>                                                                                                              
    add_activation_listener(lambda dist: dist.activate())                                                                                                                                                                          
  File "/home/vagrant/Plone/buildout-cache/eggs/distribute-0.6.28-py2.7.egg/pkg_resources.py", line 704, in subscribe                                                                                                              
    callback(dist)                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
  File "/home/vagrant/Plone/buildout-cache/eggs/distribute-0.6.28-py2.7.egg/pkg_resources.py", line 2835, in <lambda>                                                                                                              
    add_activation_listener(lambda dist: dist.activate())                                                                                                                                                                          
  File "/home/vagrant/Plone/buildout-cache/eggs/distribute-0.6.28-py2.7.egg/pkg_resources.py", line 2262, in activate                                                                                                              
    map(declare_namespace, self._get_metadata('namespace_packages.txt'))                                                                                                                                                           
  File "/home/vagrant/Plone/buildout-cache/eggs/distribute-0.6.28-py2.7.egg/pkg_resources.py", line 1847, in declare_namespace                                                                                                     
    _handle_ns(packageName, path_item)                                                                                                                                                                                             
  File "/home/vagrant/Plone/buildout-cache/eggs/distribute-0.6.28-py2.7.egg/pkg_resources.py", line 1817, in _handle_ns                                                                                                            
    loader.load_module(packageName); module.__path__ = path                                                                                                                                                                        
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pkgutil.py", line 246, in load_module                                                                                                                                                                   
    mod = imp.load_module(fullname, self.file, self.filename, self.etc)                                                                                                                                                            
  File "/home/vagrant/Plone/buildout-cache/eggs/ZopeSkel-2.21.2-py2.7.egg/zopeskel/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>                                                                                                               
    from zopeskel.basic_namespace import BasicNamespace                                                                                                                                                                            
  File "/home/vagrant/Plone/buildout-cache/eggs/ZopeSkel-2.21.2-py2.7.egg/zopeskel/basic_namespace.py", line 2, in <module>                                                                                                        
    from zopeskel.vars import var, DottedVar, StringVar, BooleanVar, TextVar                                                                                                                                                       
  File "/home/vagrant/Plone/buildout-cache/eggs/ZopeSkel-2.21.2-py2.7.egg/zopeskel/vars.py", line 2, in <module>                                                                                                                   
    from paste.script.templates import var as base_var                                                                                                                                                                             
ImportError: No module named script.templates
```

EDIT: I forgot to mention that buildout.cfg extends base.cfg, which contains the following:

```
[zopeskel]
# installs paster and Zopeskel
recipe = zc.recipe.egg
eggs =
    ZopeSkel
    Paste
    PasteDeploy
    PasteScript
    ${buildout:eggs}
```

I just tried explicitly adding `PasteScript` to the [eggs] section in buildout.cfg. After running buildout and attempting to start the server, I get a different traceback:

```
vagrant@precise32:~$ ./runbin.sh plonectl fg                                                                                                                                                                                       
instance: Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                                                                                                                                       
  File "/home/vagrant/Plone/zinstance/bin/instance", line 291, in <module>                                                                                                                                                         
    import plone.recipe.zope2instance.ctl                                                                                                                                                                                          
  File "/home/vagrant/Plone/buildout-cache/eggs/plone.recipe.zope2instance-4.2.9-py2.7.egg/plone/recipe/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>                                                                                          
    __import__('pkg_resources').declare_namespace(__name__)                                                                                                                                                                        
  File "/home/vagrant/Plone/buildout-cache/eggs/distribute-0.6.28-py2.7.egg/pkg_resources.py", line 2835, in <module>                                                                                                              
    add_activation_listener(lambda dist: dist.activate())                                                                                                                                                                          
  File "/home/vagrant/Plone/buildout-cache/eggs/distribute-0.6.28-py2.7.egg/pkg_resources.py", line 704, in subscribe                                                                                                              
    callback(dist)                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
  File "/home/vagrant/Plone/buildout-cache/eggs/distribute-0.6.28-py2.7.egg/pkg_resources.py", line 2835, in <lambda>                                                                                                              
    add_activation_listener(lambda dist: dist.activate())                                                                                                                                                                          
  File "/home/vagrant/Plone/buildout-cache/eggs/distribute-0.6.28-py2.7.egg/pkg_resources.py", line 2262, in activate                                                                                                              
    map(declare_namespace, self._get_metadata('namespace_packages.txt'))                                                                                                                                                           
  File "/home/vagrant/Plone/buildout-cache/eggs/distribute-0.6.28-py2.7.egg/pkg_resources.py", line 1847, in declare_namespace                                                                                                     
    _handle_ns(packageName, path_item)                                                                                                                                                                                             
  File "/home/vagrant/Plone/buildout-cache/eggs/distribute-0.6.28-py2.7.egg/pkg_resources.py", line 1817, in _handle_ns                                                                                                            
    loader.load_module(packageName); module.__path__ = path                                                                                                                                                                        
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pkgutil.py", line 246, in load_module                                                                                                                                                                   
    mod = imp.load_module(fullname, self.file, self.filename, self.etc)                                                                                                                                                            
  File "/home/vagrant/Plone/buildout-cache/eggs/ZopeSkel-2.21.2-py2.7.egg/zopeskel/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>                                                                                                               
    from zopeskel.basic_namespace import BasicNamespace                                                                                                                                                                            
  File "/home/vagrant/Plone/buildout-cache/eggs/ZopeSkel-2.21.2-py2.7.egg/zopeskel/basic_namespace.py", line 2, in <module>                                                                                                        
    from zopeskel.vars import var, DottedVar, StringVar, BooleanVar, TextVar                                                                                                                                                       
  File "/home/vagrant/Plone/buildout-cache/eggs/ZopeSkel-2.21.2-py2.7.egg/zopeskel/vars.py", line 2, in <module>                                                                                                                   
    from paste.script.templates import var as base_var                                                                                                                                                                             
  File "/vagrant/plone/src/hello.world/PasteScript-1.7.5-py2.7.egg/paste/script/templates.py", line 9, in <module>                                                                                                                 
    from paste.util.template import paste_script_template_renderer                                                                                                                                                                 
ImportError: No module named util.template
```

Is this an issue with my Python path? I ran `bin/zopepy` then did `import paste;print paste.__file__` and the output is:

```
/vagrant/plone/src/hello.world/PasteScript-1.7.5-py2.7.egg/paste/__init__.pyc
```

The Paste-1.7.5.1 egg directory does contain a paste/util/template.py file, but it looks like the interpreter can't find it.

Comment: What version of `Paste` is used? Look for the `Paste-...` egg line in the `zinstance/bin/instance ` script.

Comment: The only reference to `Paste*` in the `zinstance/bin/instance` script is `PasteDeploy-1.3.4-py2.7.egg'`

I have a `zinstance/bin/paster` script which containins the following lines:
`'/vagrant/plone/src/hello.world/Paste-1.7.5.1-py2.7.egg',`
`'/vagrant/plone/src/hello.world/PasteScript-1.7.5-py2.7.egg',`

Comment: For information, I've been following this guide: http://pigeonflight.blogspot.co.uk/2013/07/creating-dexterity-based-plone-add-on.html

Comment: Ah, the `PasteScript` egg appears to be missing. Try adding that explicitly.

Comment: I tried adding this explicitly (see edit above), but this caused a different traceback when running the server.

Comment: Did you add all `Paste*` eggs to the `zopeskel` entry?

Comment: It seems you included the ZopeSkel eggs in a different recipe (like the Plone recipe); you'll need to include all `Paste*` eggs whereever you do that.

Comment: You don't need to do anything, it's already included: http://plone.org/products/plone/releases/4.3

Comment: You shouldn't need to add zopeskel or zopeskel.dexterity anywhere. They're already in the kit installed with plonedev.vagrant -- which includes the Unified Installer. Just run "bin/buildout -c develop.cfg" and you should find zopeskel in your bin directory.

Do not add zopeskel or Paste* to your general eggs list. They only belong in the [zopeskel] part.

And, version pins in the [versions] section must be specific. No <=, just =. There should already be a zopeskel pin for an appropriate version.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to add Dexterity to Plone 4.3, it's already included:

- http://plone.org/products/plone/releases/4.3

Comment: Whoever down voted this: please add a comment explaining why.

Comment: +1 from me, for a correct answer and a super helpful community member.

Comment: A Matter of course :-) Just adding: Martijn's and Steve's answers are - as usual - also correct, dealing with ancient 'problems'. Congrats to everyone making the Plone-4.3-series happening, which auto-includes  Dexterity!

Answer (score 1):

As documented on the [`zopeskel.dexterity` PyPI page](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/zopeskel.dexterity/) you need to include the `PasteScript` egg too; the traceback shows you it is missing:

```
[zopeskel]
recipe = zc.recipe.egg
eggs =
   ZopeSkel < 3.0dev
   Paste
   PasteDeploy
   PasteScript
   zopeskel.dexterity
   ${buildout:eggs}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may be doing a lot more work than you need to do. The plonedev.vagrant kit comes with zopeskel and zopeskel.dexterity preinstalled. Take a look at this transcript:

```
steve@lumpy:~/plonedev_vagrant$ vagrant up
[default] Importing base box 'precise32'...
...
steve@lumpy:~/plonedev_vagrant$ vagrant ssh
Welcome to Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.2.0-48-generic i686)
...
vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-precise-32:~/Plone/zinstance$ ll bin
...
-rwxr-xr-x 1 vagrant vagrant 20023 Jul 16 01:41 zopeskel*
...
vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-precise-32:~/Plone/zinstance$ cd src
...
vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-precise-32:~/Plone/zinstance/src$ ~/Plone/zinstance/bin/zopeskel dexterity

dexterity: A Dexterity-based product
...
```

There's one bit of magic in this: due to the way the plonedev.vagrant kit symbolically links the src directory, you can't cd to it and use "../bin/zopeskel". That's why the "~/Plone/zinstance/bin/zopeskel dexterity" command is used.

We should either document that oddity or find a way to avoid it.

Comment: Update: plonedev.vagrant has been updated to document this and to create "zopeskel" and "paster" aliases that make it easy to run the commands.